# ServiceStack and MVC4 not wiring up for Api return calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I got a MVC 4 Application, to which i have added ServiceStack.Host.Mvc nuget package;
Have already  commented out

> `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)`

and added

> routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");

, the service catalog is working and i do get a valid list of services when I hit `http://{service host}:2361/api/metadata;`
I have looked via debugger the service does get called and is returning the correct data;
on the calling side though i get  following error:

### **Server Error in '/' Application.**

The task has been disposed.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ObjectDisposedException: The task has been disposed.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[ObjectDisposedException: The task has been disposed.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfDisposed() +3567641
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(Action`1 continuationAction, TaskScheduler scheduler, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +47
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(Action`1 continuationAction) +44
   ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +244
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8862676
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Comment: What version of ServiceStack are using v3 or v4?

Comment: I'm using 4, and I'm getting similar, but not sure if I am doing something incorrectly.

Comment: The first time it works, when I reload the request I get the error above as well. I am merely doing the "Hello World" so I don't think I am doing anything incorrectly.