# Why is ServiceStack returning "The task has been disposed" after initial load

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm running a VS 2010 project with the latest 4.0.5 ServiceStack that was installed via Nuget. I'm mashing together Durandal and SignalR into the mix, but I'm not sure if that could influence what ServiceStack is doing. I'm going through each OSS project and setting up the "Hello Worlds" of each. My entire source is here:

https://github.com/wtilton/DurandalServiceStackSignalR.git

https://github.com/wtilton/DurandalServiceStackSignalR

```
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
} 

[Route("/hello")]
[Route("/hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

If I navigate to (local)/api/hello/World (or call the service directly) the first time I get the expected result. The second call though seems to blow up because it is using a Thread's Task that has closed. Can anyone give me a clue what's up?

Stacktrace:

```
    [ObjectDisposedException: The task has been disposed.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfDisposed() +3544149
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(Action`1 continuationAction, TaskScheduler scheduler, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +47
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(Action`1 continuationAction) +44
   ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +119
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9042404
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

More code:

```
    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        //Tell Service Stack the name of your application and where to find your web services
        public AppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new FunqDependencyResolver(container); 
            SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "api" });

            //register any dependencies your services use, e.g:
            //container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        }
    }


    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        new AppHost().Init();
    }
```

...

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
        routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This seems to be similar to this question: [ServiceStack and MVC4 not wiring up for Api return calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602605/servicestack-and-mvc4-not-wiring-up-for-api-return-calls) but the author doesn't seem to be able to find a fix and isn't actively involved with the question it seems. The other difference is I get this error calling it directly through JS or viewing it through the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to the framework 4.5.1 and this solved the problem. Using version 4 was also giving the latest SignalR fits so upgrading seems pretty necessary in order to use the latest and greatest.

Comment: This issue may also be resolved in the next v4.06 of SS to be deployed next week.